# Folders created in Outlook 2013 not showing up as labels in GMail. Reverse does work

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I create a folder in Outlook 2013 under my GMail IMAP account it is not showing up as a label in Gmail. The other way around works perfectly, if I create a label in GMail about 10 seconds later it appears in my Outlook 2013.

This is causing me a lot of problems as I have to migrate about 250 folders to GMail. I don't want to manually create the labels (a lot of nesting as well) and then migrate the emails. I'd like to just create the folder in my Outlook 2013 Gmail IMAP account and then drag the emails to this folders. Right now I have to manually create each label in Gmail webapp, then go to Outlook 2013 and then upload the emails to the newly created folder.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that labels are not folders (multiple labels can be applied to one email, but an email can only reside in one folder), it makes sense that it does not work as folders would (even though it would make sense to create labels for folders)

I would suggest you check out [the Gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), with which you can create a script to do the label creation for you.

Comment: This is not correct as the labels created in Gmail do show up as Folders in outlook right after creation.

Comment: @Simon have a look - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10708?hl=en

Comment: hi @badge-be Thanks but If you put your IMAP prefix as [Gmail] then create a subfolder "Labels", every label you create under that label will show up as a "Folder" in Outlook 2013. Confirmed and working both ways in Outlook 2013 on another Desktop with Outlook 2013 MSI. But on this specific machine and Outlook 2013 Click To Run Edition it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I empathize with you as I also had hard times trying to migrate dozens of Outlook profiles to Gmail account.

(To me) IMAP protocol in Outlook 2013 is half broken, especially with Gmail (or Google Apps) due to the special IMAP implementation made by Google.
Also I found that using IMAP on a Gmail account works better in Outlook 2010 than with Outlook 2013 (just try to google "outlook 2013 imap empty inbox").

I suggest you to migrate your profiles to Gmail with [GAMMO](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration) and then use [GASMO](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync) to manage your e-mail accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately GAMMO and GASMO do not work in the Click To Run edition of Office 2013 or they only sync new emails coming in.

Comment: Actually I'm using GASMO with Outlook 2013 32 bit Click To Run on twenty workstations with Win 8.1 and it seems to work fine.
It is true that is not officially supported but to me GASMO is working, GAMMO instead will not even install.

Comment: GASMO does indeed work but not for migrating older emails, only new emails coming in. So it's not applicable in my use case. I advised the client to use GMail Web App for now as IMAP in Outlook2013 is horribly broken.